# Использование Java Stringer Obfuscator и onejar maven plugin

Tags: java

Для сборки проекта использую onejar maven plugin,соответственно получается 2 jar файла,первый создает плагин,а второй лежит внутри и собственно является самой программой написанной мной,встала задача провести обфускацию кода,использую Java Stringer Obfuscator
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При обфускации,как мне показалось,он проходит только по внешнему джарнику,а внутренний после этой процедуры даже нельзя открыть как архив.
Вопрос: можно ли как-то подружить Java Stringer Obfuscator и onejar maven plugin, или какой можно использовать надежный обфускатор легкий в использовании?

Comment: проводите обфускацию до сборки в один jar.

Comment: если обфусцировать внутренний,а потом заменить,программа не работает